# Coloring points on scatterplot by Variable in R

Tags: r, plot, scatter-plot

I conducted a logistic regression for the quality of wine (dataset from UCI database). I am attempting to make a scatterplot with the points colored by quality (0=low, 1=high) and have succeeded, but the colors are black and white. White points on a plot are obviously not helpful, so I wanted to be able to specify/change the colors, but I have tried many things with nothing working.

Code: 
    glm.fit=glm(wine$quality~., data=wine, 
    family=binomial)

```
step(glm.fit)

glm.fit2=glm(wine$quality~volatile.acidity
+residual.sugar+free.sulfur.dioxide+
density+pH+sulphates+alcohol,
data=wine, family=binomial)

summary(glm.fit2)

plot(wine$sulphates, wine$alcohol, 
xlab="sulphates", ylab="alcohol", 
col=wine$quality)

legend("topright", col=1:2, pch=21, 
legend=c("low quality","high quality"))
```

Here's the plot I get: 
[scatterplot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VeC3Y.png)

It's a plot of the two most significant variables from the glm. I don't really care what colors, just not white!!

Comment: `ggplot2` package and `geom_point` are probably the way to go

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As NColl suggested, the `ggplot2` package is great for this.  Try the code below, then [learn more here](https://r4ds.had.co.nz/data-visualisation.html).

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data = glm.fit2, aes(x = sulphates, y = alcohol, color = quality)) + 
  geom_point()
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple R base solution is this.

Assuming you have a df similar in structure to this one, with one binary variable containing just 0 and 1 and two more variables:

```
df <- data.frame(
  Var1 = c(sample(500, 100)),
  Var2 = c(rnorm(500, 100)),
  binaryVar = c(sample(0:1, 100, replace = T))
)
```

then you can assign colors to the binary variable using an `ifelse` statement like this:

```
df$col <- ifelse(binaryVar==0, "red", "blue")
```

and can finally do your scatter plot using `df$col` to define the colors of your data points:

```
plot(df$Var1, df$Var2, frame=F, col=df$col)
legend("topright",legend=c("Low quality", "High quality"), 
pch=1, col=c("red","blue"), bg="grey")
```

The result looks like this:
[image]

Comment: Please note that I've made an edit to the previous code, which contained a mistake in the labeling of the legend.